# how to change the toggle location to the right and drop down to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a help to change the home and about 
and the other sub menus to be to the left 
and button to the right  ..
please let me if any one knows it and the present effect is not supporting in IE9 so can an one help regarding this could be more help full for me

```js
var theToggle = document.getElementById('toggle');

   function hasClass(elem, className) {
 return new RegExp(' ' + className + ' ').test(' ' + elem.className + ' ');
}
// addClass
function addClass(elem, className) {
    if (!hasClass(elem, className)) {
     elem.className += ' ' + className;
    }
}
// removeClass
function removeClass(elem, className) {
 var newClass = ' ' + elem.className.replace( /[\t\r\n]/g, ' ') + ' ';
 if (hasClass(elem, className)) {
        while (newClass.indexOf(' ' + className + ' ') >= 0 ) {
            newClass = newClass.replace(' ' + className + ' ', ' ');
        }
        elem.className = newClass.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    }
}
// toggleClass
function toggleClass(elem, className) {
 var newClass = ' ' + elem.className.replace( /[\t\r\n]/g, " " ) + ' ';
    if (hasClass(elem, className)) {
        while (newClass.indexOf(" " + className + " ") >= 0 ) {
            newClass = newClass.replace( " " + className + " " , " " );
        }
        elem.className = newClass.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    } else {
        elem.className += ' ' + className;
    }
}

theToggle.onclick = function() {
   toggleClass(this, 'on');
   return false;
}
```

```css
/* Important styles */
#toggle {
  display: block;
  width: 28px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 30px auto 10px;
}

#toggle span:after,
#toggle span:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -9px;
}
#toggle span:after{
  top: 9px;
}
#toggle span {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

#toggle span,
#toggle span:after,
#toggle span:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #888;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* on activation */
#toggle.on span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#toggle.on span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px, 5px);
}
#toggle.on span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(7px, -8px);
}
#toggle.on + #menu {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

/* menu appearance*/
#menu {
  position: relative;
  color: #999;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Candara, "Bitstream Vera Sans", "DejaVu Sans", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "Verdana Ref", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  /* just for this demo */
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity .4s;
}
#menu:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 95px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid white;
}
ul, li, li a {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li a {
  padding: 5px;
  color: #888;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .2s;
}
li a:hover,
li a:focus {
  background: #1ABC9C;
  color: #fff;
}


/* demo styles */
body { margin-top: 3em; background: #eee; color: #555; font-family: "Open Sans", "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
p, p a { font-size: 12px;text-align: center; color: #888; }
```

```html
<a href="#menu" id="toggle"><span></span></a>

<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li><li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li><li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li><li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Using auto will automatically horizontally center the elements (toggle and menu). You can change the margin or try using float.
- Transform in CSS is not supported in IE9, u might want to try -ms-transform or -webkit-transform